# F# System.TypeInitializationException... why?

Tags: user-interface, f#, typeinitializeexception

I'm attempting to make a gui application in F# that uses a dialog box to open a file
however whenever I try to use it, the program crashes with that exception
here's my code:

```
let openAndDrawChart e = 
    let dlg = new OpenFileDialog(Filter="CSV Files|*.csv")
    if dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then // code crashes here
        let pieChart = drawChart dlg.FileName
        boxChart.Image <- pieChart
        btnSave.Enabled <- true
```

If I try to put a try with block around it, the program just crashes after the "with" keyword

Also, if I replace the code following `then` with a `()` then the program still crashes, the code never gets past the `if ... then` statement

So does anyone here know what I'm doing wrong, and how I can fix it?

I just want to point out that I'm more accustomed to making gui applications in C#, so trying to do it in F# is new to me

Here's the exception's exact words:

[image]

Comment: What's the complete wording of the exception?

Comment: @RobertHarvey is that the text you needed?

Comment: Without more of your code, it's difficult to diagnose; if I replace the part of your code following `then` with just `()` (since you didn't include definitions of `drawChart`, `boxChart`, etc.), then everything works fine on my machine.  Can you come up with a small, self-contained repro?

Comment: but if the code crashes before it even reaches that part, then that part has nothing to do with it, I just did what you did, and it crashed **on** the if

Comment: What version of F# are you using?  What is your runtime environment?  Are you compiling in Debug or Release mode?  Can you provide a minimal repro?  Keep in mind that the debugger may be a bit confused about exactly which line is causing the problem.

Comment: What happens if you change `let dlg = new ...` to `use dlg = new ...`? OpenFileDialog implements IDisposable via one of it's base classes (`Component`) so maybe that's tripping up the F# compiler somehow.

Comment: @JackP. nothing changed... at all

Comment: What is inner exception in TypeInitializationException?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so, this is a little bit embarrassing but
apparently the program doesn't play well with an entry point...

At the bottom of my code I had this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    0
```

Which I just removed... 
I didn't think it mattered much since the program executed the code above the entry point anyway

But apparently it was was enough to mess up the whole thing!

Sorry for the inconvenience, though it might be a good thing to leave this here for future reference

Comment: Have you tried adding the `System.STAThread` attribute to `main` as well?

Comment: how was that wrong? i had the same error and noticed the view details link was missing from the exception dialog in F#, in visual studio. what showed me more details errors for me was catching the exception and looking at it in the watch window. running the program from the command line also seemed to dump the details to the command line like Exception.ToString()